# Google GSI Authorization Code model errors on client.requestCode()

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My goal is to initiate an auth flow with Google via a button click on my frontend react app. Then handle the auth token request through my backend node.js server. I'm trying to implement the "auth code model" in [Google Cloud's GSI package (following the official instructions)](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model).

The error I get when I run client.requestCode() from my frontend react app is the following
`Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: c.trim is not a function. (In 'c.trim()', 'c.trim' is undefined)`

The stack trace in the browser console gives very little info, but it shows the latest issue arising in google.account code.
accounts.google.com client line 4851:

```
$p = function(a, b, c) {
                c && a.push(b + "=" + encodeURIComponent(c.trim()))
            },
```

The closest stack trace I can find that makes any sense to me is line 6522, which is called right after my frontend calls client.requestCode():

```
 "redirect" === this.ra ? (_.X("Starting redirect flow.", "CODE_CLIENT"), _.tm(window.location, _.$a(aq(this.l, this.m, a)))) : (_.X("Starting popup flow.", "CODE_CLIENT"), Er(this), Fr(this, a), this.h = _.$m(aq(this.l, this.m, a), Hr), !this.h && this.error_callback ? this.error_callback(new bq("Failed to open popup window", "popup_failed_to_open")) : Gr(this))
        };
```

My only clue at what I'm doing wrong is something is being passed to the variable "c" that isn't a string. But I don't understand anything beyond that.

This is my frontend typescript component that is just a button that I'm rendering on a page. The button should initiate the google auth flow.

```
import React from 'react';
const CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXX
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify';

function GmailAuth() {

    /* global google */
    const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        ux_mode: 'popup',
        callback: handleCallbackResponse,
        error_callback: myErrorCallback
    })
    
    async function myErrorCallback(err) {
        if (err.type == 'popup_failed_to_open') {
          // The popup window is failed to open
          console.log("ERROR! Popup window failed to open.")
        } else if (err.type == 'popup_closed') {
          // The popup window is closed before an OAuth response is returned
          console.log("ERROR! Popup window is closed before OAuth completed.")
        }
      }

    async function authEmail() {
            console.log("CLIENT:", client)
            client.requestCode();
        } 

    async function handleCallbackResponse(data) {
        try {
            console.log("Trying to handleCallbackResponse", data)
            // TODO: https
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:80/api/oauth/access', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'random_word',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });

            const content = await response.text();
            console.log('Auth code response', content);
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error fetching auth code:', error);
        }
    } 
 

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={authEmail}> Auth Google</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GmailAuth;
```

This is my index.html file which loads the accounts.google/gsi/client package:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```